# Help printing some HTML tables without breaking them across pages

Tags: printing, html

I have a page with a bunch of HTML tables that I need to print.

Each table should fit on one page, but both Firefox and Safari want to break them over multiple pages and put more than one on a page.

Is there any way to force it to not break the tables across pages?

I can use any Mac program to print.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using **Shrink to fit Page Width** in Firefox page setup and making the margins for each page bigger?

[image]

[image]

You may also want the [**Aardvark add-on**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4111) to modify a selection before printing it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want them all on separate pages, correct?

If so, and you have access to edit the HTML/CSS, wrap each table in a div and add 'page-break-after: always;' as a style for that div.

```
<div style="page-break-after:always">
    <table>......
    </table>
</div>
```

or setup a rule in your css like:

```
.pagebreak  {page-break-after:always;}
```

and add that class to each table's div element like:

```
<div class="pagebreak">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

I'm using divs for clarity, but you could also add that style to the table element in your css if you'd like.

If your content is just too big to fit one one page (which doesn't sound like the problem) then you may have to try resizing options like @John T mentions above.

-D